# BiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS but KeyPairGenerator.initialize() => java.lang.IllegalStateException on API 29

Tags: android, authentication, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Sorry for such a long question. I've tried to include all relevant information and it is quite a lot. I've been working on this issue for a few weeks now and am in desperate need of help.

## General info

I am developing a flutter app that requires authentication with a [CryptoObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject) for certain functionality. This means for Android that `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` needs to be set on the `KeyGenParameterSpec` that's used to create the key. On Android API >=30 this works fine and I can authenticate myself with either fingerprint or Device Credentials (PIN, pattern, password).

## The problem

The problem is that I can't get Biometrics with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` to work on emulators with API 29, even if they have fingerprints set up. I have not been able to test on emulators with an even lower API, so I don't know if that would work or not.

Calling `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS` as below returns true. The else case is run since `Build.VERSION_CODES.R` = API 30. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt#authenticate(androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo,androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject)) of `BiometricPrompt.authenticate()`, only `BIOMETRIC_STRONG` is allowed for devices with API <30.

```
fun canAuthenticate(context: Context): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            BiometricManager.from(context)
                .canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
        } else {
            BiometricManager.from(context)
                .canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS // <----- this returns true!
        }
    }
```

However, even though a fingerprint is registered in the emulator and `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS`, calling `keyPairGenerator.initialize()` throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one biometric must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use`.

This is the code (`restricted` is true so `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` gets set):

```
private fun initializeKeyPairGenerator(withStrongBox: Boolean = true): KeyPairGenerator {
    val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyGenAlgorithm, provider)

    try {
        val parameterSpec = createParameterSpec(withStrongBox)
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec) // <-------- It throws the exception here
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && e is StrongBoxUnavailableException) {
            val parameterSpec = createParameterSpec(false)
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec)
        } else {
            throw Exception("Cannot create key", e)
        }
    }

    return keyPairGenerator
}

private fun createParameterSpec(withStrongBox: Boolean): KeyGenParameterSpec {
    val purposes = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
    return KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, purposes)
        .run {
            setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec(ecCurveName))
            setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
            setBlockModes(encryptionBlockMode)
            setEncryptionPaddings(encryptionPadding)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                setIsStrongBoxBacked(withStrongBox)
            }

            if (restricted) {
                setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            }
            build()
        }
}
```

The issue seems very related to this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147374428.

## Some things I've tried and an ugly way to make it work with two biometric prompts

Setting `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)` on the `KeyGenParameterSpec` makes `keyPairGenerator.initialize()` not throw an exception.

```
private fun createParameterSpec(withStrongBox: Boolean): KeyGenParameterSpec {
    val purposes = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
    return KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, purposes)
        .run {
            setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec(ecCurveName))
            setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
            setBlockModes(encryptionBlockMode)
            setEncryptionPaddings(encryptionPadding)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                setIsStrongBoxBacked(withStrongBox)
            }

            if (restricted) {
                setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    setUserAuthenticationParameters(
                        0 /* duration */,
                        KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG or KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
                    )
                }
                else { // API <= Q
                    // parameter "0" defaults to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG | AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
                    // parameter "-1" default to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                    // source: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.java;l=1236-1246;drc=a811787a9642e6a9e563f2b7dfb15b5ae27ebe98
                    setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10) // <-- Allow device credential authentication
                }
            }

            build()
        }
}
```

However, it instead throws the following exception when calling `initSign(privateKey)`: ((`PlatformException(SIGNING_FAILED, User not authenticated, android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated, null`)).

Here is the code:

```
val signature: Signature
    get() = Signature.getInstance(signAlgorithm)
        .apply {
            val privateKey = asymmetricKeyPair.privateKey
            initSign(privateKey) <--- Throws an exception 
        }
```

This behavior matches with the documentation of `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds()`:

*Cryptographic operations involving keys which are authorized to be used for a duration of time after a successful user authentication event can only use secure lock screen authentication. These cryptographic operations will throw UserNotAuthenticatedException during initialization if the user needs to be authenticated to proceed.*

The documentation continues with:

*This situation can be resolved by the user unlocking the secure lock screen of the Android or by going through the confirm credential flow initiated by KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(CharSequence, CharSequence). Once resolved, initializing a new cryptographic operation using this key (or any other key which is authorized to be used for a fixed duration of time after user authentication) should succeed provided the user authentication flow completed successfully.*

Following these instructions to show a biometric prompt and listening to the result before doing `initSign(privateKey)` makes `initSign(privateKey)` not throw an exception, if the user authenticates themself in the prompt by fingerprint.

The code:

```
private fun triggerBiometricPrompt() {
    val bio = BiometricAuthenticator()
    val intent = bio.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(activity)
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
}
```

In the class FlutterFragmentActivity()

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (IdNowMethodCallHandler.handler.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        return
    }

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        handler.signWithRestrictedKey(handler.methodCall, handler.methodResult) // <-- The result gets handled here
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

However, this means the user needs to authenticate themself twice, as a second prompt of course is shown when calling `BiometricPrompt.authenticate()`.

The code:

```
private fun authenticate(
    activity: FragmentActivity,
    promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo = createPromptInfo(),
    signature: Signature?,
    onError: (Int, CharSequence) -> Unit,
    onSuccess: (BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) -> Unit,
) {
    val callback = object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) = onError(errorCode, errString)

        override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
            // Called when a biometric (e.g. fingerprint, face, etc.) is presented but not recognized as belonging to the user.
            // We want to omit it because the fingerprint maybe just failed to be read in which case the user retries.
            // Also, after multiple attempts, the user can use credentials instead.
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) = onSuccess(result)
    }
    val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)
    val prompt = BiometricPrompt(activity, executor, callback)

    if (signature == null) {
        prompt.authenticate(promptInfo) // TODO: We never do this since signature is never null.
    } else {
        prompt.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(signature)) // <-- Another prompt is shown here to authenticate 
    }
}

fun createPromptInfo(
    title: String = "Authorize", 
    subtitle: String = "Please, authorise yourself", 
    description: String = "This is needed to perform cryptographic operations.", 
): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {
    val builder = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle(title)
        .setSubtitle(subtitle)
        .setDescription(description)
        .setConfirmationRequired(true)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        builder.apply {
            setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
        }
    } else {
        builder.setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
    }

    return builder.build()
}
```

Needing the user to authenticate twice in a row with biometrics is of course a very poor user experience. It won't even work if the user authenticates with device credentials in the first prompt, and I've found no way to hide that option.

## Questions

1. Why does `KeyPairGenerator.initialize()` throw the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one biometric must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use` on emulators with API 29 with fingerprint set up, even though `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS`? Is this simply a bug in the Android system?
2. Is there a way to make keys with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` (crypto-based authentication) work on API 29 (or APIs <30)?

I am deeply grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution thanks to https://www.iedigital.com/resources/archive/create-rsa-key-pair-on-android/.

Basically, for API <30, the trick is to use `keyGuardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()` instead of using `BiometricPrompt.authenticate()`. The article explains it best but here are the basic steps with some code:

1. Do `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(0)` when creating the key.

```
private fun createParameterSpec(withStrongBox: Boolean): KeyGenParameterSpec {
    val purposes = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN
    return KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, purposes)
        .run {
            setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec(ecCurveName))
            setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
            setBlockModes(encryptionBlockMode)
            setEncryptionPaddings(encryptionPadding)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                setIsStrongBoxBacked(withStrongBox)
            }

            if (restricted) {
                setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    setUserAuthenticationParameters(
                        0 /* duration */,
                        KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG or KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
                    )
                }
                else { // API <= Q
                    // parameter "0" defaults to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG | AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
                    // parameter "-1" default to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                    // source: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.java;l=1236-1246;drc=a811787a9642e6a9e563f2b7dfb15b5ae27ebe98
                    setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(0)
                }
            }

            build()
        }
}
```

2. Use the deprecated `keyGuardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()` to display a prompt and let the user authenticate themselves.

```
fun createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(context: Context): Intent {
    val keyGuardManager = context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager

    return keyGuardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(
        "Authorize", // TODO: Add and use Phrase string https://jimplan.atlassian.net/browse/FS-946
        "Please, authorise yourself", // TODO: Add and use Phrase string https://jimplan.atlassian.net/browse/FS-946
    )
}
```

3. Sign the data

```
fun sign(signature: Signature, data: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val signedData = signature.run {
        update(data)
        sign()
    }
    return signedData
}
```

Annoying that it doesn't work for all APIs to use BiometricPrompt.authenticate(). I wish this was clearer in the documentation!